# Homepage issue/ modrewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Very new to web development/hosting/scripting.

Running an e-commerce shopping-cart hosted through network solutions on Apache with PHP.

My first issue was the cart template that I designated kept reverting to default. 
Second problem: when visiting my website (`jewelrydesignstudio.net`) the page 404s and does not redirect to the `index.php/home`.

I contacted the carts customer support to try and receive some assistance on correcting the issue(s) and this what the response.

> Thank you for contacting technical support. It looks like your server
>   doesn't have mod_rewrite enabled. Enabling that should fix it.

I have a very small amount of web dev experience, and the last time I messed with any coding or scripting was YEARS ago, but from what I remember mod_rewrite is enabled through the htaccess file on the FTP.

Here is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jewelrydesignstudio.net
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.jewelrydesignstudio.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.jewelrydesignstudio.net [R=301,L]
```

Seems that the template issue is gone, but it's still not directing to my home page when visiting (`jewelrydesignstudio.net`).

Yes I'm very new and this is pathetic :P Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Well ... it is hard to tell what EXACTLY is wrong -- I'm unfamiliar with your site at all.

Here are few suggestions (I have combined my rules with your htaccess):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jewelrydesignstudio.net
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.jewelrydesignstudio.net/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.jewelrydesignstudio.net [R=301,L]

# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# home page
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?p=home [QSA,L]
```

If I request `/index.php?p=home`, it shows the home page. The above last rule should do the job.